# Putting text into 3 posts/columns with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, text

Totally new to HTML/CSS. I've got the top image/logo done, and the header. How do i get that text formatted like in the picture (3 columns)?
I only tried using table with 3 columns. However i think its harder to style it considering its a table. Like max column width/height etc.

Thanks in advance!

[Click for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqmYB.png)

Comment: there are several ways to do this.  What have you tried?

Comment: @DCR I only tried with using <table> with 3 columns and without a border. However i think its harder to style it considering its a table. Like max column width/height etc.

Comment: A well asked question on StackExchange should contain what you've tried at least.. Provide your code.

Comment: @Professorval As said i only tried creating table with 3 columns 1 row. But finding it hard to style the text(columns) from that point.

Comment: Sorry just realized i missed some words in the original posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the three text sections, you need three child divisions in one parent division.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Style it this way:

```
.parent{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.child{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .child{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

The media query is there to make the divisions stack on one another on mobile screens.

Comment: Got it. Seems good, thanks! Question, how do i increase spacing between the three child  divs? Should i just add padding-right: 20px and padding-left: 20px in child (for ex.)

Comment: At first it was good but i changed the text inside the divs and now the text on the left and the right doesnt start at the same height as the middle text (note that middle text is the longest). Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the easiest way to do this is with the css columns attribute:

```css
div{
column-count:3;
column-gap:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>this is some random text we want to enter into our html page

</div>
```

but the better way to do this is with flex

```css
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'container'>

  <div class='cols'>this is some text</div>
  <div class='cols'>we want to add</div>
  <div class='cols'>to our html page</div>

</div>
```

if you want to add a header and a footer you can try:

```css
#container{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
#cols{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id = "header">my Header</div>
  <div id='cols'>
    <div>some random</div>
    <div> we want to add</div>
    <div>to out html page</div>
  </div>
  <div id ='footer'>my Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. This is the best answer I've seen. Better (simpler) than mine. I was not aware of this CSS property. You don't event need the container DIV - curious what its purpose is?
OP : be sure to check the Browser Compatibility chart at the bottom here. Old browsers are not supported.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count

Comment: @DCR This was helpful as well, thanks. How do add spacing between the #cols though? Tried padding in both, doesnt seem to do the work.

Comment: @DCR Ok column-gap in the container{ } seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Simply input this style

```
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

And put this code below your image code,

```
  <div class="column">
    <p>It occurs in a wide range in sub-Saharan Africa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>The Indian subcontinent to Southeast and East Asia..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>The leopard is one of the five extant </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you stay semantically correct and not use DIV tags for everything under the sun. The text in question is paragraph text thus deserves to be in a P tag.

This works for the three-column part of your question. It has the advantage of being correct semantic use of HTML tags, and using CSS to produce table-like formatting without needing to commit the sin of actually using a table like we used to do back in the 90s.

Edit: one other note. You will find that the CSS float property has its uses. However, as you use it, you will also find that overuse of it can complicate the heck out of your layout and cause you to starting pulling hair out in the end. The display table type properties are what I prefer after some years of front end work in my not-so-distant past.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .row {
      display: table-row;
    }
    .cell{
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 33.33%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <p class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus blandit neque dapibus volutpat. Donec et dapibus leo. Ut at sodales magna, quis varius lacus. Ut sapien enim, fermentum eu egestas sed, pretium vel dolor. Nullam congue odio ut sem volutpat, ac dictum mi mattis. Quisque in purus sollicitudin nisl dapibus bibendum a a quam. Sed tristique augue nisi, quis interdum odio aliquet in. Aliquam tristique, dolor sed suscipit lobortis, eros enim mattis purus, vitae consectetur ante est nec libero. Aenean semper, ipsum eget venenatis eleifend, erat erat dignissim mi, non lacinia justo lorem at tortor. Aenean et erat suscipit velit porta placerat nec sit amet augue. Nulla non sem non tellus pellentesque ornare. Vivamus volutpat eget lacus eu dignissim. Sed venenatis euismod tempus. </p>
    <p class="cell">Integer euismod felis et elit dapibus laoreet. Pellentesque et massa vitae orci pharetra imperdiet. Proin ultricies velit erat, a semper arcu volutpat eu. Morbi feugiat sapien non nisi faucibus elementum. Curabitur sed justo et enim maximus tempus. Donec posuere gravida justo sit amet dignissim. Etiam vestibulum mauris eros, vitae blandit justo pellentesque nec. Ut varius mattis volutpat. </p>
    <p class="cell">Nulla vulputate ipsum leo, ut ornare massa malesuada et. Donec metus enim, viverra id diam a, luctus sagittis turpis. Etiam euismod, ex id convallis tristique, odio tellus placerat nunc, in dapibus risus massa non nulla. In placerat lectus tortor, vel gravida leo pharetra eget. Donec mollis facilisis pharetra. Nulla commodo quam tellus, eget hendrerit nisi aliquet id. Duis sagittis enim eu sodales bibendum. Maecenas tincidunt id mauris vitae ultricies. </pclass="inline">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is not responsive, and the width of the cells are not the same. Why not use divs if they can serve?

Comment: 1) OP didn't ask for a responsive solution so I did not provide one.
2) DIVs were not intended to be used for everything. Pararagraph text belongs in P tags.

Comment: A better way to go would be to use Bootstrap. Get responsiveness out of the box, and a CSS grid layout system out of the box. The above sample is using straight HTML and CSS which is what the OP asked about - no frameworks.